# gulp creates big files and running slow

Tags: performance, gulp

I started to learn gulp and managed to understand how it works and create all tasks that i needed but i have some questions, or some things that i do not understand.

Gulp plugins i use: gulp-less, gulp-autoprefixer, gulp-minify-css, gulp-concat, gulp-uglyfly and gulp-image-optimization

So things i dont understand:

1) When i install gulp and all plugins to local project ,why is gulp creating 200mb+ of files. Files are so big my windows cant delete project and i need to move it to root of my HDD and then delete it and it takes 15 minutes to delete it? What is going on there, am i doing something wrong? Im using small portable HDD so i can use it on all computers and i wont have any space soon if i run it on all my projects.

2) Installing plugins takes about 10+ minutes. Why so long?

3) When i run default gulp task, nothing happens for first 1 minute and only then gulp starts.

I really love the idea behind gulp and i really want to use it every day but not when its running that slow. Tasks all do what i want them to do so i dont think that problem is in my gulpfile

Comment: If it takes your computer 15 minutes to delete 200mb of files, I don't think gulp is the problem...

Comment: so its normal for gulp project to be that big?

Comment: I'd have to check some actual projects (just on mobile phone at the moment so can't), but yes, that sounds pretty standard for a gulp project. It's all the package dependencies that take up the room. You install a package, it might install 20 required packages along with it

Comment: Ok, please respond when you will be at your PC, and thank you in advance. How about time for installing gulp plugins, is it instant on your PC or like 10+ min like on mine?

Comment: Just had a look, 100mb - 300mb seems to be about the average size of node_modules for my projects, so 200mb sounds pretty reasonable. The idea is to exclude that folder from version control and build on each machine, so you're not carrying around the whole lot in the repo. I just built a couple of package.json's as a test, none of them take more than 90 seconds to complete from scratch for me. I have a decent machine and internet connection, and I'm running gulp from the local SSD rather than external which probably helps

Comment: Ok so i too consider some things. I have normal portable HDD (read slow) so that is probably one of the reasons of being slow. Other one is if you and I have similar file size than reason for slow npm downloading is probably my 5mbps adsl connection so time of 10 - 15 minutes for 200mb is proportional. Thank you for your time sir!